# Gulpで建てたサーバのページがキャッシュされている?

Tags: html, gulp

Gulpを使って8000番ポートでサーバーを立てて作業していたのですが、そのあとで他のプロジェクトを同じ8000番ポートでGulpでないサーバーを建てると以前のプロジェクトのhtmlが読み込まれ、新しいプロジェクトのテンプレートが一部表示されなくなってしまいました。
表示されなくなったURLは/ルートです。直し方を教えて下さい。

gulpfileは以下のようになっています。

```
 1  var gulp = require('gulp'),
 2      webserver = require('gulp-webserver');
 3
 4
 5  gulp.task('webserver', function(){
 6    gulp.src('app')
 7      .pipe(webserver({
 8        livereload: true,
 9      }));
10  });
11
12  gulp.task('default', ['webserver']);
13
14
```